# Are there walking tours (where you join a group) in Rotterdam?

Tags: netherlands, guides, walking, rotterdam

A few weeks ago I was in Berlin, which has a huge number of excellent walking tours, many of which are free (you pay a tip at the end). These covered the usual sights, as well as some more interesting less common things. At home in Oxford, your practically can't walk down Broad Street without tripping over a group waiting for one of the few different (again mostly free) walking tours to start.

I'm going to be in Rotterdam this weekend, and I was hoping to find something similar there. However, I haven't been able to find evidence of such tours there! I can find details of self-guided ones, but I ideally want to find one with someone leading a group around offering commentary, pointing out interesting things, answering questions etc.

Do such tours exist in Rotterdam? Or have I just been spoilt by Berlin and Oxford into thinking they're very common, when in fact they're perhaps a bit of an exception?

Comment: What do you want to see in Rotterdam? Just the city center, or do you have any special interest? I am not aware of tours, as Rotterdam is not really touristic, but I wonder if there is any :)

Comment: It has some interesting architecture, so I'd expected there would be something covering some of the history of the city, and something of the more unusual/different buildings. Or something vaguely like that!

Comment: Not an official tour, but still a good option: If you're a member of [Couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.org) you could ask in the [Rotterdam group](https://www.couchsurfing.org/group.html?gid=1238) if someone is willing to give you a tour.

Comment: Not an answer, as not a walking tour, but i'd recommend a boat tour of the habour there,  I found that quite interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least a couple of options for private tours. It implies that you may be the only ones, potentially, but at least you'd have a leader to show you around, and if you have others they could come too.

Firstly, there's the [Rotterdam Walking Tour](http://www.toursbylocals.com/RotterdamWalkingTour):

> Discover the secrets of Rotterdam with a knowledgeable local guide
>   (3hrs walk)

And more promisingly, [Gilde Rotterdam Guided Tours](http://bit.ly/12KG1Ue):

> Gilde Rotterdam organizes city walks guided by senior citizens. These
>   guides will elaborate from personal experience about life in the city
>   and about the differences between Rotterdam of old and the modern-day
>   metropolis. There are several walking routes in all parts of the city
>   and two bicycle routes.

Comment: Your second link is broken unfortunately.

Comment: @Bernhard hmm, no, if you mouse over it you'll see a : in the middle - unfortunately SE is changing that to a %3a and having messing it up. I'll raise it with support.

Comment: @Bernhard - [hopefully someone will provide me with a workaround or fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187310/problem-with-in-a-link). Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I suggest bit.ly for these cases, not an ideal solution, but it works.

Comment: I saw that was the exact same hack that was suggested on your meta-question :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of great activities you can join in Rotterdam. If you are looking for free tours it's best to use Couchsurfing or MeetUp and you can find great local events. Alternatively, you can try getting in touch with the hostels they tend to have activities for non-guests sometimes. A great one is Ani & Haakien where I myself provide 4 Free Weekly Tours. You can find more information here directly [Frank Tours Rotterdam](https://www.franktoursrotterdam.com/free-tours-of-rotterdam).

I see that someone has already left a comment about Ani & Haakien above. These tours are additional to the Saturday Architecture Tour at 11 am.

Answer (score 2):

At hostel Ani & Haakien, they offer a free tour (eve if you are not staying with them. 
Starts at 11am at their door.

http://www.anihaakien.nl/atypicalrotterdamtour-hostel-ani-haakien/

Answer (score 1):

Leijnse Stadstours offers guided tours and excursions in Rotterdam.
Leijnse Stadstours has tours for every age and interest that are sure to enhance your visit to Rotterdam.
A guided tour is a great way to get oriented to the City of Rotterdam. 
Our tours are just for you, your family,collegues, students, friends and groups.

http://english.rotterdam-tours.com/

Answer (score 1):

A good friend of mine started [Walk Rotterdam](http://walkrotterdam.com/) they offer guided walking tours in english around the city of Rotterdam. Their walks are done by real architects from Rotterdam and are about architecture, art, history and the character of the city. Their [walks](http://walkrotterdam.com/walks/) include open discussions and analyses.